# How would I unit test a method that internally shuffles an array randomly

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalatest

I have a method that looks like this:

```
def compute[T](l: List[T]): List[T] = {
    val shuffled = util.Random.shuffle(l)
    // do some more computations
}
```

I wanted to seed the random number generator for my unit tests so that I don't have to break down my method into two methods and test only the computation, since this is the method that will be used externally. Is this possible to do in ScalaTest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have much background in ScalaTest, but if you call `setSeed(seed: Long): Unit` then you'll always get the same shuffle for any given seed value.

```
scala> util.Random.shuffle(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0))
res0: Seq[Int] = List(6, 0, 8, 5, 4, 7, 2, 3, 1, 9)

scala> util.Random.setSeed(57L)

scala> util.Random.shuffle(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0))
res1: Seq[Int] = List(5, 3, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9)

scala> util.Random.setSeed(57L)

scala> util.Random.shuffle(Seq(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0))
res2: Seq[Int] = List(5, 3, 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9)
```

Comment: Oh this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

how would you test the method that depends on current time? or database state? or response from google? or sleeping for some time?

generally when you test any code that depends on some external state (time, other system, or in your case: entropy / seed), you refactor that code and extract the dependency. one way, as @jwvh said is to extract seed. but imho, you should extract the whole transformation

therefore you should create a method that receives the shuffled array and test that method

Comment: or instead create some trait that abstracts over some random operations and mock it. I think it is much better approach than calling setSeed on singleton and coupling the class and the test with the implementation details.